# How do I draw a new character that is consistent with the rest of the cm family?

Tags: fonts, metafont

I want to design new characters (mainly ornaments but also mathematical symbols) for the CM modern font family using METAFONT.

What is the best way to achieve consistency with the rest of the family?

The first idea that came to my mind was to copy paste the cmbase.mf file from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/mf but that's a lot of duplication and I am not sure I am legally allowed to do so.

Comment: why would you need to copy it? It will already be in your default input path unless you have a very minimal tex installation. so you can input it just as you can input `article.cls` in latex without copying the file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So I guess the issue is with my installation, thanks for the answer

Comment: `kpsewhich cmbase.mf` should report something like `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/cmbase.mf`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for exactly, but maybe you should start with reading some metafont book (e.g. Knuth's)